# SPDisposeChecker, is this a false positive?

Tags: spdisposechecker, dispose

We have the following code:

```
    foreach (SPWeb website in collectionOfWebSites)
    {
           // Some code, no dispose of website

    }
```

SPDisposeChecker is reporting it as a memory leak. Should we dispose the website at the end of the foreach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, dispose the SPWeb here each time!

Answer (score 4):

Someone might need to back up me, but if you're getting an object from that collection, it does actually create an SPWeb instance each time (the collection is just a collection of object references rather than the objects themselves?), so you will indeed need to dispose of the object after each iteration.

Comment: That is what I though, but after I posted the question I found this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rogerla/archive/2008/02/12/sharepoint-2007-and-wss-3-0-dispose-patterns-by-example.aspx which says that you need to dispose each instance of SPWeb.

Comment: I'm pretty sure as James says - it will create an SPWeb instance for each iteration. So yes you will need to dispose of it manually after you have finished with it. Although the SPWeb won't be accessible outside the foreach it will still waste resources if not disposed.